# Updating multiple branches from master on GitHub automatically

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have a GitHub repository which has one master branch and multiple branches  created from the master, which are used for doing new work.

(This is not a coding, but a writing project, so the people working on their individual branches have very little if any experience with git or GitHub, can't use the terminal etc. They use a very simple GUI which lets them commit and push to their own branch; and pull from their own remote branch.)

The repo owner then merges changes from individual branches into the master branch. The master branch is protected and only the owner can push to it. Each individual branch is also protected so that each person working on the project always works in their own, individual branch.

Is there an automatic way to sync individual (non-master) branches with the master on GitHub? In an ideal case, on each push to the master by the repo owner, the changes would be merged back to each individual branch in the repository so that our colleagues using the GUI would be able to pull from their own branch, but that branch would always be in sync with the remote master branch.

So:

1. What would be the simplest way to achieve this type of workflow, keeping in mind the restriction that people working in individual branches can only commit and push and pull from their individual branches?
2. If the above is not possible, would it be possible if the writers were working on forks, not branches?

Comment: to use pull requests and merge if there is no conflict and use the concept of reviews, as described here: https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a script that is executed by the owner of the Repository. He needs access to the master and indiviual branches. 
Then he can rebase the changes form the master branch into the indiviual braches.

The script calls the commands for every branch.

```
git checkout <indiviual_branch_name>
git rebase master
git push <origin> <individual_branch_name>
```

If you have done this. The workers can pull their changes from the remote.

I hopen this helps.

Comment: thanks sweting! this works very well and is easy to implement in this particular context.